# Is there a way to change which pip to use at this project?

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to make a pip install of the fastf1 library. I noticed that I was using py 3.7 and that lib requires 3.8 or superior. I updated my interpreter (to python 3.10) but, the pip install keeps returning "ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement fastf1". My python --version returns 3.10, but my pip version, although updated, still calling the anaconda's pip

How do I change the main pip to be used in this project?

Terminal result:

PS C:\Users...\Github\speedmetrica\DataAnalysis> python --version
Python 3.10.0
PS C:\Users...\Github\speedmetrica\DataAnalysis> pip --version
pip 21.3.1 from c:\users\jgbal\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `python --version` is running the desired version of Python, instead of running:

```
pip install packagename
```

run:

```
python -mpip install packagename
```

That runs the `pip` module installed for that version of Python as the entry point using the same Python executable you've been running, so it will install for that version of Python as well.

If you're on Windows, and installed as admin to install [the Python launcher for Windows](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/), you can be avoid relying on the `PATH` having a specific version appear first by running:

```
py -3 -mpip install packagename
```

which will run the latest installed version of Python 3. Changing to:

```
py -3.10 -mpip install packagename
```

will force it to run the latest installed copy of Python 3.10 specifically.